# Filter results by Product Type and Sort List by Price (PHP/SQL)

Tags: php, sql

I'm in the process of learning how to create an e-commerce site. I'm trying to figure out how to order product results by price. Code below is a menu list to either filter a specific product category or the option to view all products--the code for that works.

I'm not sure how to add code to "sort by price" (low to high, high to low).
I've tried creating a function called `priceList` and calling inside the function `categoryList` (which queries the database for which product type or to view all products), but does not work.

```
    function priceList() {
      $con = getConnection();

     if($pUserCat == "lowToHigh") {
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT Price from Products
         ORDER BY Price ASC";
     } elseif($pUserCat == "highToLow") {
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT Price from Products
         ORDER BY Price DESC";

     // Execute Query -----------------------------           
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQuery);
      if(!$result) {
       echo "Cannot do query" . "<br/>";
       exit;
      }

      $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
      $count = $row[0];

      if ($count > 0) {
       echo "Query works" . "<br/>";
      } else {
       echo "Query doesn't work" ."<br/>";
      }

              // Display Results -----------------------------

      $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      for ($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
         // print_r($row);
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['Image']).'" />';
        echo "Price: " . stripslashes($row['Price']);
      }

      // Close connection
      closeConnection($con);
}
```

**Form**

```
    <!--category and price form ------------------------- -->
    <form action="register_script.php" name="frm" method="post">
        <select name="category" id="category">
            <option value="viewall">View All</option>
            <option value="dress">Dress</option>
            <option value="athletic">Athletic</option>
            <option value="sandals">Sandals</option>
       </select>

      <input type="submit" value="Go" />

  </form>


   <form action="register_script.php" name="frm" method="post">

        <select name="price" id="price">
            <option value="lowToHigh">Low to High</option>
            <option value="highToLow">High to Low</option>
       </select>

       <input type="submit" name="orderPrice" value="orderPrice" />

    </form>
    </div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    function categoryList($pUserCat=false) {
    echo "I am in category list" . "<br/>";

    $con = getConnection(); 

     $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products";

    if($pUserCat == "athletic") {
       $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products
                    WHERE ProductType='athletic'";
    } elseif ($pUserCat == "dress") {
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products
                    WHERE ProductType='dress'";
    } elseif ($pUserCat == "sandals") { 
            $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products
                    WHERE ProductType='sandals'";
    } elseif ($pUserCat == "viewall") {                 
       $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products";
    }

    // Execute Query -----------------------------           
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQuery);
        if(!$result) {
            echo "Cannot do query" . "<br/>";
            exit;
        }

        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $count = $row[0];

        if ($count > 0) {
            echo "Query works" . "<br/>";
        } else {
            echo "Query doesn't work" ."<br/>";
        }

          // Display Results -----------------------------

        $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        for ($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
           // print_r($row);
          echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['Image']).'" />';
          echo "Price: " . stripslashes($row['Price']);
        }


         // priceList();
        $priceOrder = getPriceBtn(); //$priceOrder holds value of option selected in         
     //price order menu
    priceList($priceOrder);
        // Close connection
        closeConnection($con);

}


function getPriceBtn() {    
    //echo "<br/>"."I am calling getPriceBtn function" . "<br/>";
    $priceBtn = $_POST["orderPrice"];           // price button
    return $price;
    //echo $priceBtn;
}

?>
```

[image]

Comment: don't know if it's a typo but you forgot to close you if/else before you execute the high/low query

Comment: priceList() doesn't seem to take any arguments. Is $pUserCat a global variable?

Comment: @Phill Pafford thanks for catching that, yes i forgot the closing curly brace

Comment: @dionyziz $pUserCat is a local variable that only exists inside the function categoryList. i see, i should pass $pUserCat inside priceList...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass the $pUserCat to the function priceList($pUserCat);

A tip, you should have a default query like from high to low and if the other option is selected then run that query:

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT Price FROM Products ORDER BY Price DESC";

if($pUserCat == "lowToHigh") {
   $sqlQuery = "SELECT Price FROM Products ORDER BY Price ASC";
}
```

Also you could re-write this:

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products"; // is this needed?

```
if($pUserCat == "athletic") {
   $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products
                WHERE ProductType='athletic'";
} elseif ($pUserCat == "dress") {
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products
                WHERE ProductType='dress'";
} elseif ($pUserCat == "sandals") { 
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products
                WHERE ProductType='sandals'";
} elseif ($pUserCat == "viewall") {                 
   $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products";
}
```

like this categoryList($pUserCat):

```
if($pUserCat != 'viewall') {
   $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductType='%s'";
   $sqlQuery = sprintf($sqlQuery, $pUserCat);
} else {
   $sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Products";
}
```

Comment: i appreciate the tip, i'll see if i can make my code cleaner with what you showed me

Comment: was thinking that it would work to pass $pUserCat inside priceList, but $pUserCat holds the value that the user chose in "products menu" and not the "order by price" menu. i updated the code above and include a function that is called getPriceBtn. right now it doesn't work, but i think the logic is in the right direction...

Comment: and then pass $priceOrder inside of priceList >> priceList($priceOrder);

Answer (score 0):

Local function variables are not shared. If a function variable is defined within a function, then a function that you call from within that function does not have access to the parent's local variables, which is the very reason they are called "local". You need to pass the variable as a parameter:

When defining:

```
function priceList( $pUserCat ) {
    ...
}
```

When calling:

```
priceList( $pUserCat );
```

Comment: was thinking that it would work. i know i need to pass in a variable into priceList, but a different variable not $pUserCat. $pUserCat holds the value that the user chose in "products menu" (either view all, or view atheletic, dress, or sandals). i need to pass in a variable that holds in the value of what the user selected in the "order by price" menu (low to high, high to low)